# what does the function incrementTransactionNumber() do in mongodb node driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apollo-datasource

I know the function's name seems to be self explanatory, however, after researching for quite a while I can't find a transaction number anywhere within a clientSession.
Is it an internal number ? is it possible to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction numbers are used by mongodb to keep track of operations(read/writes) per transaction per session. Sessions can be started either explicitly by calling `startSession()` or implicity whenever you create a mongodb connection to db server.

### How incrementTransactionNumber() works with sessions (explicit)

When you start a session, by calling `client.startSession()` [method](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/8b370a7ad784f5759c964cdfaec62e06c896dc95/lib/mongo_client.js#L454), it will create a new `ClientSession`. This takes in already created server session pool as one of its' constructor parameters. [(See)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/efd906a95c17ac34f5e5c68ffe5bf3bfba363dad/lib/topologies/topology_base.js#L268) These server sessions have a property called `txnNumber` which is initialized to be 0.[(Init)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/efd906a95c17ac34f5e5c68ffe5bf3bfba363dad/lib/core/sessions.js#L545) So whenever you start a transaction by calling `startTransaction()`, client session object calls `incrementTransactionNumber()` internally to increment the `txnNumber` in server session. And all the successive operations will use the same `txnNumber`, until you call, `commitTransaction()` or `abortTransaction()` methods. Reason that you can't find it anywhere within clientSession is, it is a property of serverSession not clientSession.

[ServerSession](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/efd906a95c17ac34f5e5c68ffe5bf3bfba363dad/lib/core/sessions.js#L541)

```
class ServerSession {
  constructor() {
    this.id = { id: new Binary(uuidV4(), Binary.SUBTYPE_UUID) };
    this.lastUse = now();
    this.txnNumber = 0;
    this.isDirty = false;
  }
```

So whenever you try to send a command to database (read/write), this `txnNumber` would be sent along with it. [(Assign transaction number to command)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/efd906a95c17ac34f5e5c68ffe5bf3bfba363dad/lib/core/sessions.js#L712)
This is to keep track of database operations that belong to a given transaction per session. (A transaction operation history that uniquely identify each transaction per session.)

### How incrementTransactionNumber() works with sessions (implicit)

In this case it would be called every time a new command is issued to the database if that command does not belong to a transaction and it's a write operation where retryWrites are enabled. So each new write operation would have new transaction number as long as it does not belong to a explicitly started transaction with `startTransaction()`. But in this case as well a `txnNumber` would be sent along with each command.

[execute_operation](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4f9d4ceafdcca01d49e6eeb286a9c27ddf485969/src/operations/execute_operation.ts#L192).

```
const willRetryWrite =
      topology.s.options.retryWrites === true &&
      session &&
      !inTransaction &&
      supportsRetryableWrites(server) &&
      operation.canRetryWrite;

    if (
      operation.hasAspect(Aspect.RETRYABLE) &&
      ((operation.hasAspect(Aspect.READ_OPERATION) && willRetryRead) ||
        (operation.hasAspect(Aspect.WRITE_OPERATION) && willRetryWrite))
    ) {
      if (operation.hasAspect(Aspect.WRITE_OPERATION) && willRetryWrite) {
        operation.options.willRetryWrite = true;
        session.incrementTransactionNumber();
      }

      operation.execute(server, callbackWithRetry);
      return;
    }

    operation.execute(server, callback);
```

Also read [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/transactions-background-part-6-retryable-writes) as well. And yes if you need you can get the transaction number for any session through `txnNumber` property, `clientSession.serverSession.txnNumber`.